# Core Data filter by grandparent entity relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have three entities like this:
Publisher <-------->> Author <-------->> Book

```
Publisher{
    id = <uniqueId>
    authors -->> Author
}
Author{
    id = <uniqueId>
    books -->> Book //ordered relationship
    publisher --> Publisher
}
Book{
    info = <string_with_info>
    author --> Author
}
```

I want to filter all books by Author id and Publisher id and get their info attribute . Something in the lines of:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"author.publisher.id == %@ AND author.id == %@", publisherId, authorId];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Book" inManagedObjectContext:managedContext]];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"info"]];


 NSError *error = nil;
 NSArray *results = [managedContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Where result should contain many strings with books infos.
I am not sure that the `author.publisher.id == %@` part works.

I could get the Author and then get a MutableSet with the books entities. From where I could loop over them and push their info to a new array. This does the job but I would like to do the same with only a fetch if possible.

---

**Edit**: A solution that works is changing the predicate like so:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(0 != SUBQUERY(author, $x, (0 != SUBQUERY($x.publisher, $y, $y.id like %@).@count)).@count) AND author.id  like %@ ", publisherId, authorId];
```

Some clarification. Author id is tied to publisher and unique only for that publisher. You could have two authors with the same id but with different publisher.

Expand upon the original question. Author books are ordered. Will the infos in `results` be ordered in the same order as books are ordered in Author?. The answer per my limited test is yes.

The possible id conflict has been pointed out by [Mundi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/427083/mundi) and it's been noted.

Answer (score 1):

First, after clarifying that your authorID is **not** unique, you need to use your original compound predicate:

```
NSPredicate(format: "author.publisher = %@ && author.authorID = %@",
  publisher, authorID)
```

BTW, I would replace your attribute "id" with something else because there are some potential name conflicts with "id".

But you can only fetch the author, making the predicate more concise:

```
NSPredicate(format: "publisher = %@ && authorID = %@", publisher, authorID)
```

Second, books is already a set, so no need to get distinct results. Actually, you could do this without an explicit fetch if you have the author object.

```
author.books.map { $0.info }
```

is all you need. Behold how elegant Swift can be!

Comment: Author ids are tied to publisher. It could be possible to have a second publisher with author that has the same id as another author from another publisher. It is my mistake not explaining correctly in the question. Thank you for pointing out the possible id conflict. Will fix that.

Comment: Then the logic still holds. Core Data does not care what these author ids are - the framework maintains its own ids via the relationship.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. Isn't what you are doing filtering all books that have lets say authorID = 1. And we have such authorID in two publishers. So your predicate gets PublisherOne->AuthorOne with authorID = 1->books and PublisherTwo->AuthorTwo with authorID = 1->books. Now you have a result with both authors' books.

Comment: Your authorIDs are not unique. Thus, they are not a primary key, and they are not used as foreign keys in other tables. They are just some attribute. Let the relationship manage these details - that's what Core Data is for. I will change the predicate to reflect this.

Comment: Ok I believe I understood you now. However I do want to use them as well as the profileID to filter. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @"author.publisher = %@", publisher . Isn't publisher in this part of your suggestion referring to NSManagedObject for the entity Publisher. What I wanted is `-(NSArray*)getBooksInfoesOfAuthor:(NSString*)authorID withPublisher:(NSString*)publisherID`. Probably I can't explain myself correctly :/